# I created a class to return a confidence interval after bootstrapping, but my confidence interval looks oddly narrow. What did I do wrong?

Tags: python, statistics, confidence-interval, resampling

My intent is to have the code perform bootstrapping (statistics) on a given list
with sample size equal to the length of the list 10,000 times and then calculate
the 95% confidence interval.

```
import numpy
from random import choice

class bootstrapping(object):

    def __init__(self,bslist=[],iteration=10000):
        self.bslist = bslist
        self.iteration = iteration

    def CI(self):
        listofmeans = []

        for numbers in range(0,self.iteration):
            bootstraplist = [choice(self.bslist) for _ in range(len(self.bslist))]
            listofmeans.append(sum(bootstraplist) / len(bootstraplist))

        s = numpy.std(listofmeans)
        z = 1.96
        n = self.iteration**0.5

        lower_confidence = (sum(listofmeans) / len(listofmeans)) - (z*s/n)
        upper_confidence = (sum(listofmeans) / len(listofmeans)) + (z*s/n)

        return lower_confidence,upper_confidence

test = bootstrapping([60,33,102,53,63,33,42,19,31,86,15,50,
                      45,47,26,23,30,20,18,48,22,20,17,29,43,52,29],10000)
test.CI()
```

The confidence interval I'm getting,(37.897427638499948, 38.102572361500052), is
oddly narrow. When I enter the same list of numbers into Minitab, the 95%
confidence interval I get is (30.74, 47.48). Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: Unless you set a [random.seed()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed), it will give different choices across runs. This won't account for the discrepancy, but is worth fixing for future testing.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate a little further?

Comment: setting a specific random seed makes it so that it will give you the same choices every time you run it: it's useful for testing whether the algorithm works with known input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a 95% confidence interval, let `z = 1.96` (approximately) and compute the interval about the mean, plus or minus `z*std` where `std` is the standard deviation. In other words, use `z*std` not `z*std/n`:

```
import numpy as np
import random
random.seed(2017)

class Bootstrapping(object):

    def __init__(self,bslist=[],iteration=10000):
        self.bslist = bslist
        self.iteration = iteration

    def CI(self):
        listofmeans = []

        for numbers in range(0,self.iteration):
            bootstraplist = [random.choice(self.bslist) for _ in range(len(self.bslist))]
            mean = sum(bootstraplist) / len(bootstraplist)
            listofmeans.append(mean)

        mean = np.mean(listofmeans, axis=0)
        std = np.std(listofmeans, axis=0)
        z = 1.96
        err = z*std
        lower_confidence = mean - err
        upper_confidence = mean + err

        return lower_confidence, upper_confidence

test = Bootstrapping([60,33,102,53,63,33,42,19,31,86,15,50,
                      45,47,26,23,30,20,18,48,22,20,17,29,43,52,29],10000)
print(test.CI())
```

yields

```
(31.309540089458281, 46.876348799430602)
```

---

Alternatively, you can compute the confidence interval without appealing to the mean +/-1.96*std formula. You can get an empirical estimate of the confidence interval by sorting `listofmeans` and finding the values at the 5th and 95th percentile:

```
import random
random.seed(2017)

class Bootstrapping(object):

    def __init__(self,bslist=[],iteration=10000):
        self.bslist = bslist
        self.iteration = iteration

    def CI(self):
        listofmeans = []

        for numbers in range(0,self.iteration):
            bootstraplist = [random.choice(self.bslist) for _ in range(len(self.bslist))]
            mean = sum(bootstraplist) / len(bootstraplist)
            listofmeans.append(mean)

        listofmeans = sorted(listofmeans)    
        a, b = round(self.iteration*0.05), round(self.iteration*0.95)
        lower_confidence = listofmeans[a]
        upper_confidence = listofmeans[b]

        return lower_confidence, upper_confidence

test = Bootstrapping([60,33,102,53,63,33,42,19,31,86,15,50,
                      45,47,26,23,30,20,18,48,22,20,17,29,43,52,29],10000)
print(test.CI())
```

yields

```
(32.888888888888886, 45.888888888888886)
```

Comment: What does random.seed() do?

Comment: It ["seeds" the random number generator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) so the result is repeatable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the confidence interval is `mean += z*stderror`, where the standard error = (standard deviation) / sqrt(n). The standard error is simply the standard deviation of the *sampling* distribution.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In this case, std = np.std(listofmeans, axis=0) gives the standard error, without having to take the square root of n. From what I understand, if I knew the population standard deviation, which I don't in this case, then I would divide by square root of n.

Comment: @ShingTse Ah, yes. I think I see now. I was confused by the bootstrapping. Yes, you have `listofmeans`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It is a bit confusing because there are so many means here. But I think what bootstrapping is doing is similar to surveying the height of 10000 boys, finding the mean and std deviation of those heights, and then taking the mean +/- 1.96*std. We're not computing the standard deviation of a mean, only the standard deviation of a sample.

Comment: I added [a second way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40491298/190597) to compute the confidence interval which is perhaps more true to the spirit of bootstrapping -- by finding it empirically, not by formula.

Comment: Yes, we are sampling means *directly* in this case.

Comment: @unutbu One more question, I don't see the random.seed() method used in the body of the code. Did I miss something? Where does this method change what the code does?

Comment: @ShingTse: My mistake. I should have called `random.seed`, not `np.random.seed`, since we are using `random.choice`, not `np.random.choice`. I've updated the code above to fix this. *Now*, when you run the code, the result should be repeatable.

Comment: To finish the analogy mentioned above, we are finding the interval which includes 95% of the boys.